# TypeScript error ts(2345) is incorrectly labeling the type of object in Vue v-for loop

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am using Vue single file components. Here is a small example showing my error:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

interface IDesign {
  displacement_map_urls: { [key: string]: string }
}

const props = defineProps<{
  design: IDesign
}>()

// function to convert string to title case
const toTitleCase = (str:string) => {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt:string): string { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase() })
}

</script>


<template>
  <div >
    <div v-for="(url, face ) in props.design.displacement_map_urls">
      <span>{{ toTitleCase(face)}}</span>
      <span>{{ url }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Visual Studio Code underlines `face` in the template with this error:

```
const face: string | number
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

For some reason ts thinks that the `face` variable is a `string|number`, however if you look at the interface `IDesign` you can see that the displacement_map_urls is an object with string keys and string values.

I think this has something to do with the Vue `v-for` loop, because if I manually grab the first key without going through a `v-for` loop then VSCode does not show an error:

```
{{ toTitleCase(Object.keys(props.design.displacement_map_urls)[0]) }}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide anything else to help solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`face` is the index into displacement_maps_urls.  It is type `string | number` because displacement_maps_urls could be an array (or an integer-keyed object).  I think the parser isn't smart enough to always get the types of the Vue template properties right.

`string | number` cannot be automatically cast to `string` because sometimes it's a number.  But since in your case you know it's always a string, you can just cast it manually (`face as string`):

```
<template>
  <div >
    <div v-for="(url, face ) in props.design.displacement_map_urls">
      <span>{{ toTitleCase(face as string)}}</span>
      <span>{{ url }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: > "displacement_maps_urls could be an array (or an integer-keyed object)"
I have defined it as `displacement_map_urls: { [key: string]: string }` so should't that be enough for the compiler?

Comment: I would think so, too.  But if you declare 'let x: {[key:string]: string};` then `x[1]` is still valid syntax.  I think it might be that this typescript syntax of declaring the index type is a special case that's really just telling the compiler that x is a normal object.  And such objects can be simultaneously keyed by strings and numbers.